# Why is python looping creating double results?

Tags: python

I  have 3 lat/lngs and a URL that I am constructing.  My output should be 3 URLs, for each lat/lng, I am receiving 6.  What do I need to change in my code below to print 3 URLs instead of 6?  The try block and first for loops start are error handling, if the script fails, try twice.  I am getting 6 values even when the script does not fail.

```
 def main():
    for i in range(2):
        for attempts in range (1):
            try:
                for lat, lon, id_, startDate, endDate in zip(latval, lonval, idVal, startDayValStr, endDayValStr):
                    time_param = '?start='+ startDate +'T'+ "01:00" + 'Z' + '&end='+ endDate + 'T' + "23:00"  + 'Z'
                    hrPrecip = 'https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/hourly-precipitation/' + str(lat)+'/' + str(lon) + time_param + '&unit=inches'
                    print hrPrecip
            except Exception as e:
                attempts = i + 1
                sleep(30)
                print "now trying attempt #" +  " " + str(attempts) + " " + "for error"  " " + str(e)
                print(traceback.format_exc())
                logging.exception(e)
                msg = "PYTHON ERRORS:\nTraceback info:\n" + traceback.format_exc()
                logging.debug("sending error email")
                emailserver.email_error_msg(msg)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/hourly-precipitation/44.797207/-95.175648?start=2019-05-13T01:00Z&end=2019-05-13T23:00Z&unit=inches
https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/hourly-precipitation/44.796302/-95.180946?start=2019-05-13T01:00Z&end=2019-05-13T23:00Z&unit=inches
https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/hourly-precipitation/44.778728/-95.23022?start=2019-05-13T01:00Z&end=2019-05-13T23:00Z&unit=inches
https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/hourly-precipitation/44.797207/-95.175648?start=2019-05-13T01:00Z&end=2019-05-13T23:00Z&unit=inches
https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/hourly-precipitation/44.796302/-95.180946?start=2019-05-13T01:00Z&end=2019-05-13T23:00Z&unit=inches
https://insight.api.wdtinc.com/hourly-precipitation/44.778728/-95.23022?start=2019-05-13T01:00Z&end=2019-05-13T23:00Z&unit=inches`
```

Comment: If any one URL fails, you retry *all* of them. Even if nothing fails, you have the outer loop that runs the entire process twice.

Comment: What's the purpose of `for attempts in range(1):`? That just loops 1 time, which is the same as not having a loop at all.

Comment: There's nothing in the `try` block that does anything with the URL that could fail. Is there code missing that tries to connect to the website?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Try everything twice if there's an error, but only once if they all succeed?

Comment: I do not need the second for loop, try everything once, if it fails once, try again, if it fails the second time that's it.  I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the try: and except: block. failing in the first. I am guessing you do not need the second loop with attempt in range(1). In fact you do not need any loop here.

Comment: All they're doing in the `try` block is concatenate strings and printing it. If it fails they don't print anything.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your comment.